# How to convert JBPM project into Web- service?

Tags: web-services, jbpm

I have a working JBPM project that i want to expose as a web service so from my server i can call that web-service. So please let me know is there a any way to expose a JBPM project into a web service.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can use the jbpm-console service to expose the processes you have deployed there as a REST service.  You can also expose your project yourself as a web service using for example the camel integration component (and using camel to set up a WS endpoint) or by writing a custom wrapper yourself.